# LEFT join has missing dates/gaps when working with generate_series()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a summary report of sales per year with a couple of tables like the following:

| products |
| --- |
| id (PK) |
| [... ] |

| Orders |
| --- |
| id (PK) |
| date |
| product_id (FK to products |

I've written a query where I select from a time series built from the oldest to the most recent orders and then left joined that with the two tables, grouping by product_id and year timestamp:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('year'::text, years) AS year,
    products.id as product_id,
    coalesce(count(o.id),0) AS total_orders
   FROM generate_series(
       (select MIN(orders.date) from orders),
       (select MAX(orders.date) from orders),
       '1 year'::interval
   ) years
     left JOIN orders o ON date_trunc('year'::text, years) = date_trunc('year'::text, o.date)
     join products on products.id = o.product_id
     
  GROUP BY year, products.id
  ORDER BY year, products.id
```

The result of the query looks like this:

| year | product_id | total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | 1 | 4 |
| 2013-01-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2013-01-01 | 2 | 1 |

Due to the left join, I was expecting to see another row with coalescing the null results to zero:

| year | product_id | total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | 2 | 0 |

Any ideas as to why the left join on the time series is not being returned as a row pointing at zero `total_orders` when no rows exist in `orders` for the given year?

Comment: In order to count `NULL` returns you must use `LEFT JOIN` --  Does changing `join products ` to `LEFT JOIN products` help here?

Comment: @Zak sadly, no, changing the second join to a LEFT JOIN doesn't have any effect on the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all years since the earliest one, and for each of them, all possible products with `total_orders` for each. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/nMTWFzkT)

```sql
SELECT 
 years.year  AS year,
 products.id AS product_id,
 count(o.id) AS total_orders
FROM generate_series(
    (select date_trunc('year', MIN(orders.date)) from orders),
    (select MAX(orders.date) from orders),
    '1 year') AS years(year)
  JOIN (select distinct id from products) AS products ON true
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON years.year = date_trunc('year',o.date)
                     AND products.id = o.product_id
GROUP BY year, products.id
ORDER BY year, products.id
```

1. There's no need to `coalesce(count(o.id),0)`.
2. If you `date_trunc()` in `generate_series()`, you don't need to repeat it elsewhere.

---

I think you might be reading your joins wrong. For your expected output to appear, this:

```sql
years LEFT JOIN orders ... INNER JOIN products ...
```

Would have to be evaluated like this:

```sql
years LEFT JOIN (orders ... INNER JOIN products ...)
```

Meanwhile, it's evaluated sequentially, left-to-right, like so:

```
(years LEFT JOIN orders ...) INNER JOIN products ...
```

And it's outlined [in the `SELECT` doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) along with a hint on how you can force alternative behaviour:

> Use parentheses if necessary to determine the order of nesting. In the absence of parentheses, `JOIN`s nest left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

See example. I think, group orders by product_id and year can be do on table orders before join to other tables, assuming  orders table is largest table and has indexes on product_id and orders.date.

```
SELECT 
     years
    ,products.id as product_id
    ,coalesce(o.total_orders,0) AS total_orders
FROM products
LEFT JOIN generate_series
   (
       cast(date_part('year',(select MIN(orders.date) from orders)) as int),
       cast(date_part('year',(select MAX(orders.date) from orders)) as int),
       1
   ) years on 1=1
LEFT JOIN 
  (
     select product_id,date_part('year', orders.date) as order_years
               ,count(*) total_orders
     from orders
     group by product_id,date_part('year', orders.date)
  ) o
  ON years = o.order_years and o.product_id=products.id
ORDER BY years, products.id
```

Let's take a small example of data

```
create table products (id int,ProductName varchar(20));
insert into products values
 (1,'apple')
,(2,'banana')
,(3,'lemon')
;
create table orders (id int, date date,product_id int);
insert  into orders values
 (1,'2012-02-28',1)
,(2,'2012-03-28',2)
,(3,'2013-03-28',3)
;
```

The basic query is the report framework - joins years and products

| years | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 |
| 2012 | 2 |
| 2012 | 3 |
| 2013 | 1 |
| 2013 | 2 |
| 2013 | 3 |

Subquery, grouping orders

```
select product_id,date_part('year', orders.date) as order_years
               ,count(*) total_orders
from orders
group by product_id,date_part('year', orders.date)
```

has result

| product_id | order_years | total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012 | 1 |
| 2 | 2012 | 1 |
| 3 | 2013 | 1 |

Join for above queries has result

| years | product_id | total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 | 1 |
| 2012 | 2 | 1 |
| 2012 | 3 | null |
| 2013 | 1 | null |
| 2013 | 2 | null |
| 2013 | 3 | 1 |

as expected, we have null's in some positions - there use `coalesce`